# excess elements in aggregate initializer

Tags: c++, arrays, initialization, gnu

```
static const double convTable[4][4] =
{
    {1.0,           1000.0,     1000000.0,  1000000000,0    },
    {0.001,         1.0,        1000.0,     1000000,0       },
    {0.000001,      0.001,      1.0,        1000.0          },
    {0.000000001,   0.000001,   0.001,      1,0             }
};
```

I have this array, in a header file, but it won't compile, Not sure why?

Comment: This shouldn't be in a header.

Comment: `won't` compile? What's the real thing?

Comment: You have extra commas in the first, second, and fourth sub-items. Look at the *last* entries for each.

Comment: oh I see some extra commas

Comment: Why don't you see warnings ?
`excess elements in array initializer`, get rid of commas in last elements

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using commas instead of points in some of the items, so you have more than 4 items per row.

```
{1.0, 1000.0, 1000000.0, 1000000000,0 }
                                   ^
```

should be

```
{1.0, 1000.0, 1000000.0, 1000000000.0 }
```